# Function expressions can't be named. doc error

Tags: flutter, debugging, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Hello in my flutter project i got this problem when i want to recall users by thier ID.

```
Future<UserModel> getUserById(String id)=> _firestore.collection(collection).doc(id){
    print("==========id is $id=============");
    debugPrint("==========NAME is ${doc.data()['name']}=============");
    debugPrint("==========NAME is ${doc.data()['name']}=============");
```

it gives an error on [ .doc(id){ ]

what shall i do?

an also in my order page it gives same error somehow

```
_firestore.collection(collection).doc(id).setData()({
      "userId": userId,
      "cart": convertedCart,
      "id": id,
      "total": totalPrice,
      "createdAt": DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      "description": description,
      "status": status
    });
  }
```

what do you guys think?

in that line

```
_firestore.collection(collection).doc(id).setData()({
```

setData is error

my flutter version is 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below.

```
  Future<UserModel> getUserById(String id){
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("collectionPath")
        .doc(id).get().then((doc) => UserModel.fromSnapShot(doc.data()));
  }
```

Your fromSnapshot don't return a UserModel. It should look like this.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

@immutable
class UserModel{
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String stripeId;
  final List<CartItemModel> cart;
  final int totalCartPrice;

  const UserModel({required this.id, required this.name, required this.email, required this.stripeId, required this.cart,
      required this.totalCartPrice});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'stripeId': stripeId,
      'cart': cart,
      'totalCartPrice': totalCartPrice,
    };
  }

  factory UserModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return UserModel(
      id: map['id'] as String,
      name: map['name'] as String,
      email: map['email'] as String,
      stripeId: map['stripeId'] as String,
      cart:  (map['cart'] as List).map((cart) => CartItemModel.fromMap(cart)).toList() ,
      totalCartPrice: map['totalCartPrice'] as int,
    );
  }
}

@immutable
class CartItemModel{
  final String id;


  const CartItemModel({required this.id});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
    };
  }

  factory CartItemModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return CartItemModel(
      id: map['id'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sir again in this line (_firestore.collection(collection).doc(id).setData({) setData gives error

Comment: How did you get your Id?

Comment: You cannot call `.setData({)`, you must close it like `.setData({})`

Comment: sir here's my code in both pages.

https://ibb.co/XxYjTX3
https://ibb.co/CVPPcL5

Comment: get or set? In the second image it's get.

Comment: get or set i change it to see which one is work...

by the way why that doc in first image dosen't work?

https://ibb.co/Mk68K34
https://ibb.co/8g65hF2

Comment: I update my anwser

Comment: Again fromSnapshot gives an error

Comment: Could you give the code inside UserModel?

Comment: since i couldn't paste it all in comment i screenshot them

https://ibb.co/74TJ57c
https://ibb.co/HVjRH7d
https://ibb.co/926Pcr1

Comment: It's the whole structure to enhance. Don't put static content into model and function.